# Distributed vs Centralised configuration

Tags: javascript, architecture

We're building an app based on Flux/React - and we're trying to establish a *scalable* pattern for configuring routes and registering dependencies. The two approaches we have can be broadly categorised as 'distributed' vs 'centralised'

#### DISTRIBUTED:

This version allows us to distribute configuration around the application, and allow sub-teams to work on their piece of the app without having to edit several files.

```
var app = new App

app.register([
  re  quire "dependencyA",
  require "dependencyB",
  require "dependencyC"
])

// dependencyA
module.exports = function (app) {

  // registers self with application
  app.registerItem('foo', {

    // method called by application on 'start'
    start: function (app) {

    // can obtain previously registered things in start method
      var previouslyRegisteredThing = app.getRegisteredItem("thing")
    }
  });

  // returns some configuration
  return {
    routeName: "foo",
    path: "/path/to/foo"
  }
}


// App
var App = {

  registry: {}
  config: {}

  registerItem: function (name, stuff) {
    this.registry[item] = stuff;
  },

  register: function (items) {
     for(item in items) {
         // let's item attach itself
         itemConfig= item(this);

         // dynamically add configuration
         this.config = extend(this.config, itemConfig)
     }
  },

  getRegisteredItem: function(key) {
      return this.registry[key];
  }
}
```

#### CENTRALISED:

In this version, the application has to name each dependency, and also each route. This is more explicit, so that you don't have to fish around to figure out where a config item is coming from:

```
var app = new App
app.register({
    a: require "dependencyA"
    b: require "dependencyB"
    c: require "dependencyC"
});

app.routes({
  foo: "path/to/foo"
});

// dependencyA: borrows angular-ish dependency injection
module.exports = ['b', 'c', function (b, c) {
    return {
      start: function () {
          return c.doSomethingElse()
      }
    // dependencies are now in scope
  }]
}

// App
var App = {
  register: function (items) {
      _.each(items, function (itemSpec, name) {
          this.registry[name] = itemSpec
      }, this);
  },
  initialize: function () {
      // WARNING: handwaving...

      _.each(this.registry, function (itemSpec, name) {
          moduleFun = itemSpec.pop();

          dependencies = []
          _.each(itemSpec, function (item) {
              if (this.registry[item]) {
                  dependencies.push(item);
              } else {
                throw new Exception("registry didn't have one of those");
              }
          });

          // replace the item in the registry so it can be started later
          this.registry[name] = moduleFun.apply(moduleFun, dependencies);
      }
  }
};
```

The concern here is that the application configuration will become too unwieldy, and hard to manage once the project/team scales past a certain size.

I prefer the centralised version, as it is more explicit and the application is dictating the names of its "children". What are the pitfalls of the latter approach? In what circumstances would you choose the former?

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: I know, but is there a stack for this sort of question?

Comment: in it's current form, unlikely. ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773) On the other hand, why don't you just [edit] out invitation for debate and opinion polling; as far as I can tell you seem to have rather a reasonable question at the core

Comment: I would welcome an edit...